# Documentation not appearing in doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to document a C API which is all contained in a single C Header file. When I run doxygen, on the file, it's giving me errors for currently undocumented C Macros, but when I add the necessary documentation for macros, although the undocumented errors are cleared, the macros plus documentation do not appear in the doxygen generated html output.

Only a fraction of the documented header file, the structures, actually appears in any doxygen output. I can't see anything in configuration settings or documentation that would assist in clarifying why doxygen does not place documented code from the header file into its generated output.

Does anybody know why this would be the case?

Answer (score 4):

See items 2 and 3 of the FAQ: http://www.doxygen.org/manual/faq.html

In short you are likely missing a comment block with `@file` to document your header file.

Comment: The @file comment is in the file and none of the solutions in the faq make a difference. They are written in a class based way talking about namespaces but since I'm a straight C Header so that might explain why the faq solutions aren't helping me.

Comment: @file should have worked, so please post a self-contained example (either here or in doxygen's bug tracker) so I can reproduce the problem myself.

Comment: Oops! The @file does document a lot more, in the actual file documentation but what I'm really missing is the API functions. Unfortunately in the header the API functions are declared as C pointers to functions. I'm documenting them with a "\fn" but these don't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to feed my xml files to oxygen. It does not work with xml as input. You need to feed actual source files.